# Can I check for instantiation of ALL objects in a Java array at once?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a global array of length 3 of type Employee objects. It is a dummy class for a demo of Swing API (you need not concern with the details here)

Objects when instantiated (but individual members not initialized) are set to "null". I want to check if all the objects are null in a SINGLE STATEMENT, meaning here I need a solution that does not involve any "for" loop.

Basically, I am looking for library method which can do this for me quickly in a single call.

PS: I am using Java nearly 3 years, so kindly excuse any rookie mistakes - asking a question on SVO after ages! :)

Comment: *"Can I check for instantiation of ALL objects in a Java array at once?"* No.  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: *"quickly in a single call."* Quick for you as the programmer? Make a factory method, use an IDE. Quick to run? Design tight code, but know that every solution that might be found in Java requires a loop of some form. (And I think the same would be true of all high level computer languages.)

Comment: I don't believe programming needs to feel like a chore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some Java 8 features if you prefer not to use an explicit loop.

For example :

```
String[] arr = new String[3];
System.out.println (Stream.of (arr).anyMatch (Objects::nonNull));
```

will print `true` if any of the elements in the array is not null.

```
System.out.println (Stream.of (arr).noneMatch (Objects::nonNull));
```

will print `true` if all the elements in the array are null.

Comment: Thanks.. accepting your answer.. but I found a different solution myself i.e.  created a method without loops to check if the object is empty, then while looping to read the array, I just check if the object at current location is empty (i.e. array element populated with object reference, but object itself is null). To do so, I have used a piped string of conditions with an IF block and each member is being compared to null..

as soon as an object is detected null, we break out of the reading loop..